# Regular expression to match a line and extract file name in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have a String in following format

```
Index: /aap/guru/asdte/atsAPI.tcl
===================================================================
RCS file: /autons/atsAPI.tcl,v
retrieving revision 1.41

Index: /aap/guru/asdte/atsAPI1.tcl
===================================================================
RCS file: /autons/atsAPI1.tcl,v
retrieving revision 1.41
```

What I want is to match a line start with `Index:` and then get the file name from path.

I mean first get `Index: /aap/guru/asdte/atsAPI.tcl` and then extract `atsAPI.tcl` as final result.

Currently I am using matching twice, first whole line and then extracting file name.

My question is, how to do it in a single regular expression in java.

Current Code is

```
String line = "Index: /aap/guru/asdte/atsAPI.tcl\r\n===================================================================\r\nRCS file: /autons/atsAPI.tcl,v\r\nretrieving revision 1.41\r\n\r\nIndex: /aap/guru/asdte/atsAPI1.tcl\r\n===================================================================\r\nRCS file: /autons/atsAPI1.tcl,v\r\nretrieving revision 1.41";
Pattern regex1 = Pattern.compile("Index:.*?\\n", Pattern.DOTALL);
Pattern regex2 = Pattern.compile("[^*/]+$");

Matcher matcher1 = regex1.matcher(line);
while (matcher1.find()) {
    String s = matcher1.group(0);

    Matcher matcher2 = regex2.matcher(s);
    while (matcher2.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher2.group(0));
    }
}
```

Comment: https://codebunk.com/b/128141613/

Comment: You don't need `DOTALL` flag which made you append a newline to your un-greedy dot. `.` doesn't match newlines by default.

Comment: @g_p I've included how to do it using one regex alongwith a working demo in my answer. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to do it in a single regular expression in java.

Use a **capturing group** as shown below. 
Regular Expression:

```
^Index:.*\/(.*)
```

Now the filename can be obtained by using `matcher.group(1)` and is represented by the last part `(.*)` in the regex

- `^` matches starting anchor
- `Index:` matches the literal as-is
- `.*` matches anything (greedy)
- `\/` matches a slash `/`
- `(.*)` matches the filename in a capturing group

Make sure `(?m)` or `Pattern.MULTILINE`  flag is set so that the matching is multi line and matches the starting anchor `^` at the start of every line.

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8gL7BZ/1/)

**EDIT:** Modify your code to use only one regex, like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^Index:.*\\/(.*)", Pattern.MULTILINE);

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}

// Output: 
atsAPI.tcl
atsAPI1.tcl
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/l53Ucm)

Answer (score 0):

Try this `^Index.+\/([^\.]+\.\w+)$` with the `gm` flags or `Index.+\/([^\.]+\.\w+)` without the `m` flag. The only capturing group is for the name of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regex, the answer is in the first match group:

```
Index:.*?\/([\w]+\.[\w]*)
```

You can debug it in the following link:
[Regex link](https://regex101.com/r/HFM2J4/1)